# Blocking/waiting stack operations

Tags: c++, stack

This was an interview question to me in Oracle.

There is a stack and a push operation should wait till it completes even if a stack is full and a pop operation should wait till it completes even if the stack is empty.

How can we achieve this?

### My answer

Let a thread do the push & pop operation. Push thread has to wait till stack has a vacant space and the pop thread has to wait till the stack has at least one element.

Comment: Your answer is fine, and you should add it as a self-answer to your question. The title is confusing: Your operations *are* blocking and specified as blocking.

Comment: If the operation is blocking , then it would go on infinitely right? If the push blocks the stack and wait for a pop to happen, it would go on indefinitely. Am I correct?

Comment: Normally, "blocking" describes an operation that blocks its thread of execution until the necessary resources (e.g. room in the stack) become available.

Comment: +1: They asked a textbook question you gave the simple answer. If they had asked for more detail you could've have gotten into mutexes and conditions but the stack can't be full and empty at the same time right? As thiton said blocking isn't deadlocking ;-)

Comment: I tried to clarify the title a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocking/waiting stack operation can be achieved by having a thread do this task.

If the stack is full, the push thread(thread which does the push operation) makes a blocking push operation. So it waits to push until the stack has a space left(until a pop happens).

If the stack is empty, the pop thread(thread which does pop operation) makes a blocking pop operation. So it waits to pop until the stack has at least one element(until a push happens).

Answer (score 1):

Two semaphores?  Load one, 'A', with the stack depth limit, create the other, 'B' empty.  Every thread that wants to push a value has to wait for a unit from 'A', pop the value and then signal a unit to 'B'.  Every thread that wants to pop has to wait for a unit from 'B', pop the value and then signal a unit onto 'A'.

If the stack is not thread-safe, you will need a mutex/critical section as well to protect the stack from multiple access.